# Fetch online multiple data on one text field after loop array catches the first element only javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am fetching some rows of data from online and i append it on textfield ,but when i loop these data with array ,i get only the first row only and i guess it's because all rows have the same id which i get by using `getElementById` . i don't know how to handle this situation .

Html :

```
 <div class="Coordinates">
                    <input type="text" class="a" id="latitude" 
value="@d.latitude">
                    <input type="text" class="b" id="longitude" value="@d.longitude">
```

javascript :

```
   var latidudedb =[];
   var longitudedb =[];
   latidudedb .push(document.getElementById("latitude").value);
   longitudedb.push(document.getElementById("longitude").value);
   var  newArray = latidudedb.concat(longitudedb);
   for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
   var data = newArray[i]
    console.log(data ); 
   }
```

Comment: You can use the `id` attribute one time on your dom. if you want to make a shared attribute you can use `class` attribute instated.

Comment: Do you mean you have that HTML repeated, once for each row? If so, your HTML is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique in the document.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder   I mean that once data from online database are attached to input fields `id` get duplicated therefore when i  loop to the array i get the first row only

Comment: Again: `id` values **must** be unique. Only one element, anywhere on the page, is allowed to have a given `id` value. If you have `id="latitude"` on more than one element, the HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you have that HTML repeated, once for each row? If so, your HTML is invalid. `id` values **must** be unique in the document.

But you have a class, so you can use that. Your latitude elements have the class `a`. <s>You haven't shown your `latitude` elements</s> *(Now you have)*, but let's assume they have clas `b` *(and I assumed correctly! :-) )*:

```
var latidudedb = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".a"),
    function(input) {
        return input.value;
    }
);
var longitudedb = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".b"),
    function(input) {
        return input.value;
    }
);
console.log(latidudedb);
console.log(longitudedb);
```

`document.querySelectorAll` gets a collection of elements matching the given selector. We apply `Array.prototype.map` to them to get their values as an array, then output the result.

Live example:

```js
var latidudedb = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".a"),
    function(input) {
        return input.value;
    }
);
var longitudedb = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".b"),
    function(input) {
        return input.value;
    }
);
console.log(latidudedb);
console.log(longitudedb);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="Coordinates">
  <!-- London -->
  <input type="text" class="a" value="51.5085300">
  <input type="text" class="b" value="-0.1257400">
  <!-- Rome -->
  <input type="text" class="a" value="41.8919300">
  <input type="text" class="b" value="12.5113300">
  <!-- Istanbul -->
  <input type="text" class="a" value="41.0138400">
  <input type="text" class="b" value="28.9496600">
</div>
```

As of ES2015, we can use `Array.from` (which can be polyfilled) instead, perhaps with an arrow function (which can't, but can be transpiled):

```
var latidudedb = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".a"), input => input.value);
var longitudedb = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".b"), input => input.value);
console.log(latidudedb);
console.log(longitudedb);
```

Live example:

```js
var latidudedb = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".a"), input => input.value);
var longitudedb = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".b"), input => input.value);
console.log(latidudedb);
console.log(longitudedb);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="Coordinates">
  <!-- London -->
  <input type="text" class="a" value="51.5085300">
  <input type="text" class="b" value="-0.1257400">
  <!-- Rome -->
  <input type="text" class="a" value="41.8919300">
  <input type="text" class="b" value="12.5113300">
  <!-- Istanbul -->
  <input type="text" class="a" value="41.0138400">
  <input type="text" class="b" value="28.9496600">
</div>
```

Comment: you'are  right  i have have not shown longitude, but i updated, your code is working now. blessings